# Summary of inner group in a cell in the outer group

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a section of a report that has an outer group with an inner group.  Some of my users will print this report while some will not.  I'd like to be able to to keep the toggle capabilities while providing a summary on the outer group of the top 3 rows of the inner group.  Basically, I'd like the notes column to see the top three defects and their total counts.

I could accomplish this by doing the work in SQL, but in this case I'd prefer, if possible, for the report server to handle the summary and grouping.

```
Outer Group             Sum(Defects)           First(DefectId)
  Inner Group           Sum(Defects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using CTE

```
    with MyCte AS (SELECT     
                                                         MachineCode + ' | ' + Tool + ' | ' + comments + ' | ' + Operator + ' | ' + convert(nvarchar(50), MinutesDown) + ' ||| ' 'Things',
                                                         Reason, 
                                                         MinutesDown,
                                                         PartitionedRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Reason ORDER BY MinutesDown DESC)
                                 from        #Comments)
    insert into #t
    select  *
    from    MyCte
    where   PartitionedRowNum <= 3
```